# Migrations error __fake__.Does Not Exist: Tag matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

**Migration**

```
def add_startup_data(apps, schema_editor):
    Startup = apps.get_model('organiser', 'Startup')
    Tag = apps.get_model('organiser', 'Tag')
    for startup in STARTUPS:
        startup_object = Startup.objects.create(
            name=startup['name'],
            slug=startup['slug'],
            contact=startup['contact'],
            description=startup['description'],
            founded_date=startup['founded_date'],
            website=startup['website'])
        for tag_slug in startup['tags']:
            var=Tag.objects.get(slug=tag_slug)
            startup_object.tags.add(var)

def remove_startup_data(apps, schema_editor):
    Startup = apps.get_model(
        'organiser', 'Startup')
    for startup in STARTUPS:
        startup_object = Startup.objects.get(
            slug=startup['slug'])
        startup_object.delete()
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
     dependencies = [
        ('organiser', '0002_tag_data'),
    ]
     operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(
            add_startup_data,
            remove_startup_data)
    ]
```

I get the following error:

```
self.model._meta.object_name 
__fake__.DoesNotExist: Tag matching query does not exist.
```

I can’t seem to fix it. I tried `get_object_or_404` but it just leads to another error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch the `Tag.DoesNotExist` exception as follows:

```
    for tag_slug in startup['tags']:
        try:
            var=Tag.objects.get(slug=tag_slug)
            startup_object.tags.add(var)
        except Tag.DoesNotExist:
            pass
```

The `get_object_or_404` shortcut catches the exception and raises `Http404` instead. When you do this inside a view, this causes Django to show the 404 error page. It doesn't make sense to use `get_object_or_404` in a migration, because it is not a view.